# New-VirtualEnvironment command freezes the powershell window

Tags: python, windows, powershell, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Just trying to get configured for python and django dev on my windows 10 box.

I've got Python 2.7 installed and I'm using pip to install virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper-powershell packages.

Use the following to import the package

```
import-module virtualenvwrapper
```

so far so good, then i run

```
New-VirtualEnvironment projectathena
```

and the powershell window hangs. nothing happens, no folder is created insice my virtualenvs folder, left it for 30 mins, but still nothing. anyone else seen this? fixed this?

edit:
after the suggestion below, i can see that line giveing the problem is line 72 in VirtualEnvWrapper.psm1

```
        & $global:VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV $Name $global:VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS
```

which i read to be run Virtualenv.exe with the name of the env and any arguments.

So I've tried running this in ps, cmd and an admin cmd and it hangs every time. it starts to run and then does nothing else. it does the same when invoked without the env name either. in fact i can't even get it to show the syntax help with

```
virtualenv.exe /?
```

im going to log this as an issue on the virtualenv package bugs page (which im guessing might be the wrong place), but anyone else seen this? or got suggestions as to why it wouldnt run?

Comment: Try adding `Verbose` and `Debug` switches to your command: `New-VirtualEnvironment projectathena -Verbose -Debug`. Maybe it will produce some output, so we can guess what's happening.

Comment: there is no output when run with both those, as if the command isn't even starting

Comment: Well, then I'd suggest importing module, opening `VirtualEnvWrapper.ps1` from the module directory in PS ISE, setting breakpoint in the `New-VirtualEnvironment` function  and running `New-VirtualEnvironment projectathena` command. When breakpoint fires, use `F10` to step over the code and note on what line it hangs. Restart, repeat, but press `F11` to step into that code, then proceed with `F10`. Eventually, you'll find what makes it hang and then you can update your question with more info.

Comment: awesome suggestion. love it when someone reminds me of the tools i need to fix the issue. best way. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was down to  Avast Anti Virus software.

In avast, goto the settings, goto Active Protection, go to File System Shield and add an exclusion for

```
C:\Python27\Scripts
```

This should work without a reboot, did for me, I was having issues with the Virtualenv.exe which is in that folder.